# Grails / Gorm and Postgresql Unaccent

Tags: postgresql, grails, grails-orm, unaccent

I have a question about how to use unaccent extension of PostgreSQL with Grails.

I have a lot of descriptions in french and PostgreSQL is not accent insensitive. I installed the unaccent extension and it works very well on PgAdmin III.

How can I configure Grails and/or PostgreSQL to use unaccent in my controller ?

This is my Domain:

```
Class Description {
   String content
   int type = -1
}
```

For example, can I "translate" the next query using GORM ?

```
SELECT content 
FROM description 
WHERE unaccent(content) ILIKE unaccent(%myInputHere%)
```

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is SQL specific you will need to use an [SQL Restriction](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/api/grails/orm/HibernateCriteriaBuilder.html#sqlRestriction%28java.lang.String%29) within your criteria. For example:

```
def myinput = params.myinputfieldname
def results = Description.createCriteria().list() {
  sqlRestriction "unaccent(content) ILIKE unaccent('%$myinput%')"
}
```

At least that's the idea.

**Edit**

Take care to note the fact 'content' in the restriction above refers to the actual SQL column name instead of the domain's field name.

Comment: @ArrrghGrails Note when you use `sqlRestriction` then actual column names has to be used instead of domain object's field names. `content` used in above answer reflects the column name in table.

Comment: @dmahapatro Excellent point (Will edit post to include this warning).